# Blur "a" in mobile

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm using Bootstrap to create a responsive page and since that page can get a little long I added a "Back to Top" button that floats at the bottom of the page. The markup for that is:

```
<a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

The styles I have for it are:

```
a.back-to-top,
a.back-to-top:active,
a.back-to-top:visited,
a.back-to-top:focus {
    display: none;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    background: #F4AA00;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.back-to-top:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background: #562E18;
}
```

And here's the Jquery script I have related to that element as well:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(".table-wrapper").length) {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $(".table-wrapper").offset().top) {
            $('a.back-to-top').fadeIn('fast');
        } else {
            $('a.back-to-top').fadeOut('fast');
        }
    }
});

$("body").on("click", "a.back-to-top", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".table-wrapper").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});

$("body").on("mouseup", ".btn, a", function() {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

On mobile whenever I tap that "Back to Top" button (in this case an `a` element) it keeps the styling it has for `:hover`. The only way for the element to revert to the default styling is if I tap outside of it. It doesn't look like `blur()` works - I made sure that the event handler is properly bound and it is.

Please help me as I'd like that button to go back to it's default styling.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the hover effect in a media query so that it only applies to desktop sizing.

It's probably not the solution you are looking for, but unless you're using the browser shrunken down on desktop, it's a simpler answer.

```
// Apply only when the screen is 768px or wider.
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  a.back-to-top:hover,
  a.back-to-top:active {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #562E18;
  }
}
```

Comment: But then on mobile the element won't change colors if you click on it.

Comment: Try adding the :active pseudo class from the other CSS selector you have to the one in the media query? I updated the answer.